# Synonimize [parameterized-query] into [prepared-statement]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The description for [parameterized-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameterized-query) says:

> A pre-compiled and optimized SQL statement that can be executed multiple times by changing certain constant values during each execution. Often used to prevent SQL injection.

The description for [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement) says:

> A Prepared Statement (or parameterized statement) is a precompiled SQL statement that serves to improve performance and mitigate SQL injection attacks. Prepared statements are used in many popular Relational Database Management Systems.

Both refer to the same thing in my opinion. They describe prepared SQL statements that use data binding (parameterization) to pass the data to the database.

Can they be synonymized, please?

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't directly add it as a synonym, as [parameterized-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameterized-queries) was already a synonym for the tag [parameterized-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameterized-query). Therefore, I had to first remove the synonym and then add both of them as synonyms to [prepared-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statements). The synonyms are now set up as:

[parameterized-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameterized-queries) → [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement) (× 5691)
[parameterized-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameterized-query) (× 309) → [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement) (× 5691)

As usual, I'll wait for a couple of days before merging them, to provide us with an option to rollback, if in case there are issues with the synonym.